# Coding with Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to make a program where a user can input a name, and the program will search through the file line by line until it has a match, then return all the match. So this is what i Have, I got the file into the program, but cant seem to code the program to search the file for the user input. Any help?

Assignment: this what the code has to be able to do.

**read in each row, parse out the name part, perform a match on names, if match return full name, else move to next row.  Have message if you reach the end without a match.**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

    public class USpres {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

            File file = new File ("USPres.txt");
              Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

                System.out.println("Please enter the name you would like to search for: ");
                String name = kb.nextLine();

                while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                {

                 if(scanner.nextLine() == kb)
                 { 
                           System.out.println("I found " +name+ " in file " +file.getName());

                       }
                           break;
```

Comment: Press ctrl shift F

Comment: Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: you are comparing strings using the `==operator`, use `equals()` instead, an of cause dont  compare `kb` with `scanner.nextLine()`, but `name`

Comment: @Exagon:  They're not even comparing strings, which is the unfortunate part.  `kb` is an instance of `Scanner`.

Comment: @Makoto oha sorry my fault, fixed it

Comment: @KevinHooke I understand what you are saying but I'm not a computer person this is a require course, I really need help with this. please, check out the code give me a hint to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @pimpvader every you are doing wrong is mentioned in my comment

Comment: @Exagon the code ask me for the name, then does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(scanner.nextLine() == kb)
{ 
    System.out.println("I found " +name+ " in file " +file.getName());

}
```

should become

```
if(scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
{ 
    System.out.println("I found " +name+ " in file " +file.getName());

}
```

just like they said above in the comments. Also, .equals() is meant to compare two Objects, not two strings. Since they are both strings, you may have success with this method, but I would suggest always using .equalsIgnoreCase() when comparing Strings.

Comment: It is best to avoid `nextLine` inside `if` conditions. For instance what if we want to test if line starts with `A` and ends with `.`? Someone could write code like `if (scanner.nestLine().startsWith("A") && scanner.nextLine().endsWith("."))` and be surprised why this doesn't work as he expects. Problem with such approach is that each time we call `nextLine()` this method returns next line, so each call moves us to another line. So `startsWith` will test first line, but `endsWith` will try to test second line. It is always better to store result of `nextLine` in variable and use it later.

Comment: so this is what I was able to piece together,

Comment: File file = new File ("USPres.txt");
                              Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in)Scanner     scanner = new Scanner(file);
System.out.println("Please enter the name you would like to search for: ");
        String surname = kb.nextLine();
        String name =  file.getName();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
         if(scanner.nextLine().endsWith("surname"))
         {
   System.out.println("I found " +name+ " in file " +file.getName());         }   
         {

Comment: Yes, it was answered. Multiple people explained why you would never find a match the way you were going about it. If you expected to come here and have someone do your work for you, you were greatly mistaken. If you have another question pertaining to your post, I suggest you make that clear. Otherwise, please keep to posting relevant material, not complaining that no one answered.

Comment: @SteveManC  if you know how to "read each line from a file, parse out the name part, perform a match on names to a user input that you get using Scanner kb, and  if match return print full name, else move to next row. Have message if you reach the end without a match, say something,

Comment: @SteveManC I thank you for the help in revising my code, but it didn't WORK!!! I DONT KNOW how to parse out a name in a file and match it to a user input, by either first or last name" alright, "Thanks A LOT"

Comment: Maybe your question was misunderstood. In your file, do you have lines consisting of first and last names that you are trying to match exactly, or are you trying to match a first name to any of the listed names that contain that first name, and same for last name? The code that was provided will give exact matches, not considering capitalization, if a line contains a name like 'John Smith' and your user types in 'john smith' or any variant with capitalization.